# How to stop PHP code running when in a child theme

Tags: php, child-theme, masonry

I understand you can add extra CSS on top of the parent theme, but how do you remove PHP code from functions.php?

I want to remove the `Masonry plugin` in `twentyfourteen` theme, and have located the piece of code on `line 254`.

```
    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-masonry' );
    }
```

If I'm editing the parent theme, I can just comment this block out `/*  */`.

But I'm not aware of a way to change this is my child theme.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actually "remove" PHP code from the parent theme. What you can do is undo things done there.

The counterpart of `wp_enqueue_script` is `wp_dequeue_script`.

If you put this in your `functions.php` it should remove the `Masonry Plugin` (untested)

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'de_script', 100 );

function de_script() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-masonry' );
}
```

Source: [Function Reference/wp dequeue script @ Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script)

As I haven't tested this be aware of the fact that this could have unwanted side effects if the theme relies on the `Masonry Plugin`.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks to both of you. The Masonry plugin was adding inline styling to my footer widgets which stopped them from working between 800 and 900px, so I'm quite happy with ripping it out. But I'll keep my eye on any other issues!

Answer (score 2):

I think, if your problem its just that script, you just can deregister it your child theme:

```
function deregister_jqmasonry() {
   if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' ) ) {
       wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-masonry' );
   }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'deregister_jqmasonry', 100 );
```

High priority of add_action ensures it runs at the end.